# Dealing with NODATA_VALUE of ascii grid in qgis2threejs plugin?

Tags: qgis, raster, ascii, nodata, qgis2threejs

For a project I have modelled the upper and lower boundaries of geologic layers in the subsurface. The resulting rasters are stored as ASCII files with a `NODATA_VALUE` of -999. However, when I visualize the ASCII file, using the qgis2threejs plugin, the pixels or cells that have `nodata` are shown as 0 (see images below).

Is it possible for the qgis2threejs plugin to recognize cells with a `nodata` value and visualize only the part of the raster with valid values?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a polygon layer that represents the area that data exist and use it for the "Clip DEM with polygon layer" option.

http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/ExportSettings.html#clip

[image: Screenshot1-ClipDEM]

[image: Screenshot2-ClipDEM]